# How to avoid waiting for a method to finish in c#?

Tags: c#, loops, methods

I am writing a code in c# where I want to call a method which has a loop in it and call another method after that. The problem is that the loop in the first method runs for the duration of the program and so the second method cannot be called because the first method is never completed.

Example:

```cs
private void Menu()
{
 Game();
 Movement();
}

private void Game()
{
 do
 {
  // some code inside the loop
 } while (x > 9);
}

private void Movement()
{
 // some other code
}
```

Comment: You need to look into multi threading.

Comment: i would actually suggest you ditch the idea for now. Multi-thread and thread synchronization is a beast you can't tame as a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are writing a game.

When writing a game (or any kind of event driven application), you will need to do certain things at certain times.   For example, the graphics should be drawn (50 or 60 times a second), key presses need to be processed (perhaps 10 times per second), mouse movement (20 times a second) etc etc.

One simple (but perhaps not the best), way to do this is to use a counter that ticks once every 10 milliseconds, then your 'timer-events' can react to this.

```
void Loop()
{
     int ticks = 0;
     var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

     while(true)
     {
        stopwatch.Start();
        if(ticks % 20 == 0) // Once every 20 ticks (or 200 ms)
        {
            DrawGraphics();
        }
        if(ticks % 50 == 0) // Once every 50 ticks (or 500 ms)
        {
            ProcessKeyPresses();
        }

        ticks++;
        stopwatch.Stop();

        Thread.Sleep(10 - stopwatch.TotalMilliseconds); // Wait until at least 10 milliseconds have passed
     }
}
```

Obviously, this is very simplistic, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the easiest way of dealing with my problem from what I can see in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Many games do not use multi-threading. They use a game loop which looks like this

```
while (gameIsRunning) {
    ProcessInputs();
    UpdateGameWorld();
    GenerateOutputs();
}
```

You must store the state of every object (avatars, spaceships, bombs ...). According to the user inputs and the current game time `UpdateGameWorld` updates the state of each object. The state includes the positions, speeds, vital functions, energy, life-time etc.

Then `GenerateOutputs` uses this updated state information to generate the output.

---

Since the time its takes perform one loop can vary, its best to look how much time has elapsed since the last loop by using a `StopWatch`. Speeds and positions are calculated like this

```
newSpeed = speed + delta_time * acceleration
position = position + delta_time * 0.5 * (speed + newSpeed)
speed = newSpeed
```

Here acceleration, speed and position are vectors (2D or 3D depending on the type of the game).

The acceleration is given by gravity, drag, thrust, gas, breaks etc.